# cakePHP prevent user enter URL

Tags: url, cakephp

I use router

```
Router::connect(
    '/articles/:id/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('id', 'slug'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

BUT how to prevent user enter `/articles/view/:id` .I can make page /articles/view/:id  become " NOT FOUND " ?

Comment: I don't get it what you want. Do you want the pages without a slug be not found? Just do a redirect or $this->error(404) when the slug is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Router::connect(
    '/articles/view/:id',
    array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'index'),
);
```

Comment: I can make page /articles/view/:id  become " NOT FOUND " ?

Comment: would work, but just makes for an extra route to manage, and for cake to parse (more overhead)

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the slug, so just check that $this->params['slug'] isset and if it is not, redirect them to the home page.